Can you get a Cypress test to do a file upload for a p-fileUpload?
I have an app that makes use of a p-fileUpload that I'm writing a Cypress test for.
I thought maybe I could do this using the selectFile method - but that hasn't worked.
Here is my p-fileUpload implementation in the html:
<p-fileUpload
    name="files"
    [url]="url"
    accept="text/xml"
    [multiple]="true"
    (onBeforeUpload)="onBeforeUpload($event)"
    (onUpload)="onUpload($event.files, $event.originalEvent.body)"
    (onError)="onError($event.files, $event.originalEvent ? $event.originalEvent.body : $event.error)"
    [attr.data-cy]="'fileUpload'"
  ></p-fileUpload>

And here is my attempt to upload a file in my Cypress test:
cy.get('[data-cy="fileUpload"]').should('be.visible')
        .then($upload => {

            cy.get('[data-cy="fileUpload"]').selectFile('cypress/fixtures/myfile.xlsx');

});

and here's the error I get:
cy.selectFile() can only be called on an <input type="file"> or a <label for="fileInput"> pointing to or containing a file input, but received the element:
<p-fileupload _ngcontent-dan-c234="" name="files" accept="text/xml" class="p-element" ng-reflect-name="files" ng-reflect-accept="text/xml" ng-reflect-url="transaction/api/v2/upload/xml?" ng-reflect-multiple="true" data-cy="fileUpload">...</p-fileupload>

Any suggestions?
Thanks much.

Try with the drag-drop option.
cy.get('[data-cy="fileUpload"]')
  .selectFile('cypress/fixtures/myfile.xlsx', {action: 'drag-drop'})

When you use this option Cypress searches within child elements of <p-fileUpload> for the <input> to which it will attach the file.
Inspecting the HTML in dev-tools/Elements tab you should be able to find an <input> underneath the main element, for example (omitting some attributes)
<p-fileupload>
  <div class="p-fileupload">
    <div class=" p-fileupload-buttonbar">
      <span class="p-button">
        <input type="file" />


I have a file upload component based on jQuery Plugin blueip-fileupload. I am testing it using Cypress. I cannot directly call selectFile through the input type='file 'element, but I can use the method of enter link description here by selecting the entire parent element and then using drag-drog.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
